# Erro ao fazer update de imagem no banco

Tags: php, mvc

> Notice: Undefined index: flefoto in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inf4m\asteroide\controllers\usuario_controller.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined index: flefoto in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inf4m\asteroide\controllers\usuario_controller.php on line 19

Arquivo **views/cadastro_usuario.php**

```
<form action="router.php?controller=usuario&modo=novo" method="post">

<input id="teste" class="botao_foto_perfil" type="file" name="flefoto"/>

<input class="box_text" type="text" name="txtnome">

<input class="box_text" type="text" name="txtemail">
```

Arquivo **router.php**

```
$controller = $_GET['controller'];
$modo = $_GET['modo'];

switch($controller){
  case 'usuario':

  require_once('controllers/usuario_controller.php');
  require_once('models/usuario_class.php');

  switch($modo){
    case 'novo':

    $controller_usuario = new controllerUsuario();
    $controller_usuario::Novo();
    break;
  }
}
 ?>
```

Arquivo **controllers/usuario_controller.php**

```
class controllerUsuario {

  public function Novo(){

    $usuario = new Usuario();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        //Tratamnto de arquivo
        $arq = basename($_FILES['flefoto']['name']);

        $caminho = $_FILES['flefoto']['tmp_name'];

            if(strstr($arq,'.jpg') || strstr($arq,'.png') ||strstr($arq,'.gif')){
                    $usuario->foto = $_POST['flefoto'];
                }else{
                    echo("Este não é um arquivo de imagem");
                }

            }

    $usuario->nome = $_POST['txtnome'];
    $usuario->email = $_POST['txtemail'];
    $usuario->senha = $_POST['txtsenha'];

...
```

Comment: `$_POST['flefoto'];` não existe.

Comment: onde eu crio ela?

Comment: Creio que esteja tentando fazer o seguinte, em vez de: `$usuario->foto = $_POST['flefoto'];` seria `$usuario->foto = $arq;`

Comment: Ja conseguiste resolver?

Comment: Para imagens, você busca com o `$_FILES`, e não `$_POST`. Olhe o link do Woss.